# Why Hello World still shows after the string is deleted?

Tags: android

Trying my first Android app, deleted the "Hello World" string but still seeing it when running on my device. Why?

Another question is, how can I set it to another value? For example, I'd like to set it to "Application created" at the end of `OnCreate()`

This is my `OnCreate()` function, nothing changed:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
  }
}
```

This is my `activity_main.xml`, just simply deleted the "Hello World" string in the Graphical Layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.dqtools.egg.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: did u clean ur project and ran it again?

Comment: try installing the modified app again in your emulator

Comment: You are deleting the Hello world `TextView` from `activity_main.xml`..Instead, delete it from `fragment_main.xml`

Comment: @Lal, thanks. This solves my question. How do I accept your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deleting the Hello world `TextView` from `activity_main.xml`..Instead, delete it from `fragment_main.xml`

Answer (score 0):

go to res>values>strings
there change

```
 <string name="hello_world">Hello World</string>
```

to

```
<string name="hello_world">Anything u want</string>
```